# What happened to the Grail Knight?

Tags: indiana-jones, indiana-jones-and-the-last-crusade

In *Indiana Jones and the Last Crusade*, we see the Knight wave goodbye to group as the cave itself is collapsing, but the structure is still standing in the end.

Did the Knight get crushed, or does he live forever behind the Great Seal? I mean, he's supposed to be either immortal or undying from old age – could he have survived the cave-in?

Answer (score 7):

The price for immortality was for the cup for the Holy Grail to never cross the Great Seal.

Elsa Schneider and Walter both wanted to take the Holy Grail out of the temple, breaking the only condition for immortality.

In any case, I don't think the old Knight would live forever even if he weren't crushed.  The other Knights were mentioned in dialogue from the rest of the movie as having died of extreme old age.  Without the Grail to replenish his life force, the Knight probably died soon after (if he survived the cave-in)

Comment: what if the Holy Grail magically reappeared in its proper position?  Would that enable the old knight to not die of old age?  And wouldn't magically reappearing in its proper position be the type of mystical power the Holy Grail might be imagined to have?

Comment: @M.A.Golding, magic vs miracle, different things.  In all Biblical stories, to break a covenant with God has dire consequences (ref Face-melting Nazis in *Raiders of the Lost Ark*).  In my opinion, they all were lucky that the collapse of the temple was the only consequence.  Old Testament Jehova might have given them all the same instant age treatment that Walter got for choosing poorly